# Cumulative sums in python without itertools

Tags: python, list, if-statement, for-loop

I was wondering is there a way of creating a list of cumulative sums in Python ***without*** using any of the itertools or by just using for loops and if statements?

Comment: could you give a sample input and output

Comment: What's wrong with the answers given in [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15889131/953482)?

Comment: Input ([0, 1, 2, 3])

Comment: @simonman Don't add extra information in comments; edit it into your question