# Splitting a list into uneven groups?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, split, sublist

I know how to split a list into even groups, but I'm having trouble splitting it into uneven groups.

Essentially here is what I have: some list, let's call it `mylist`, that contains x elements.

I also have another file, lets call it second_list, that looks something like this:

```
{2, 4, 5, 9, etc.}
```

Now what I want to do is divide `mylist` into uneven groups by the spacing in second_list. So, I want my first group to be the first 2 elements of `mylist`, the second group to be the next 4 elements of `mylist`, the third group to be the next 5 elements of `mylist`, the fourth group to be the next 9 elements of `mylist, and so on.

Is there some easy way to do this? I tried doing something similar to if you want to split it into even groups:

```
for j in range(0, len(second_list)):
    for i in range(0, len(mylist), second_list[j]):
        chunk_mylist = mylist[i:i+second_list[j]]
```

However this doesn't split it like I want it to. I want to end up with my # of sublists being `len(second_list)`, and also split correctly, and this gives a lot more than that (and also splits incorrectly).

Comment: What should happen if you run out of elements in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution keeps track of how many items you've written. It will crash if the sum of the numbers in the `second_list` is longer than `mylist`

```
total = 0
listChunks = []
for j in range(len(second_list)):
    chunk_mylist = mylist[total:total+second_list[j]]
    listChunks.append(chunk_mylist)
    total += second_list[j]
```

After running this, `listChunks` is a list containing sublists with the lengths found in `second_list`.

Comment: @J.P., can you share what your `second_list` looks like? This code works fin in my test cases.

Comment: Let me double check on my data (mylist is really long) and make sure - it made be a problem on my end in which case I think this would work! I'll double check on it and accept your answer once I do. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

You can create an iterator and [*itertools.islice*](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
seclist = [2,4,6]

from itertools import islice
it = iter(mylist)

sliced =[list(islice(it, 0, i)) for i in seclist]
```

Which would give you:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Once *i* elements are consumed they are gone so we keep getting the next *i* elements.

Not sure what should happen with any remaining  elements, if you want them added, you could add something like:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ,14]
seclist = [2, 4, 6]

from itertools import islice

it = iter(mylist)

slices = [sli for sli in (list(islice(it, 0, i)) for i in seclist)]
remaining = list(it)
if remaining:
    slices.append(remaining)
print(slices)
```

Which would give you:

```
 [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14]]
```

Or in contrast if there were not enough, you could use a couple of approaches to remove empty lists, one an inner generator expression:

```
from itertools import islice

it = iter(mylist)
slices = [sli for sli in (list(islice(it, 0, i)) for i in seclist) if sli]
```

Or combine with [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
 from itertools import islice, takewhile

it = iter(mylist)
slices = list(takewhile(bool, (list(islice(it, 0, i)) for i in seclist)))
```

Which for:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
seclist = [2, 4, 6,8]
```

would give you:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

As opposed to:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [], []]
```

What you use completely depends on your possible inouts and how you would like to handle the various possibilities.

Comment: Nice use of `islice` -- consuming different amounts of items from *the same* iterator.  +1

Comment: wish i could upvote twice; such an extremely useful answer i put it into my personal general purpose tool library.

Answer (score 7):

A numpythonic approach:

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> sec = [2, 4, 5]
>>> np.split(lst, np.cumsum(sec))
[array([0, 1]), array([2, 3, 4, 5]), array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]), array([11])]
```

And here is a Python3.X approach using `itertool.accumulate()`:

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> sec = [2,4,6]
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> sec = list(accumulate(sec_lst))
>>> sec = [0] + sec + [None] if sec[0] != 0 else sec + [None]
>>> 
>>> [lst[i:j] for i, j in zip(sec, sec[1:])]
[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using list-comprehensions together with slicing and [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function (all *basic and built-in* tools of python):

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
seclist = [2,4,6]

[mylist[sum(seclist[:i]):sum(seclist[:i+1])] for i in range(len(seclist))]

#output:
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

---

If `seclist` is very long and you wish to be more efficient use [`numpy.cumsum()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) first:

```
import numpy as np
cumlist = np.hstack((0, np.cumsum(seclist)))
[mylist[cumlist[i]:cumlist[i+1]] for i in range(len(cumlist)-1)]
```

and get the same results

Comment: This was my initial solution too, but I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way than computing 2*len(seclist) sums.

Comment: @jedwards one can build the [cumulative sum list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list) first if he worried about efficiency

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was headed -- `seps = [sum(seclist[:i]) for i in range(len(seclist)+1)]; 
lists = [mylist[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(seps, seps[1:])]`

Answer (score 1):

```
subgroups = []
start=0
for i in second_list:
  subgroups.append(mylist[start:start + i])
  start = i + start
```

At the end `subgroups` will contain the desired lists

Example run:

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> second_list = [2,4,5,9]
>>> subgroups = []
>>> start=0
>>> for i in second_list:
...    subgroups.append(mylist[start:start + i])
...    start = i + start
...
>>> subgroups
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Padraic has the best solution IMO, but I'll chime in with this hacky one liner that requires no imports:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # source list - could be any iterable
>>> S = [2,3,4] # group sizes - could be any iterable

>>> [ [ [ next(i) for k in range(j) ] for j in iter(S) ] for i in [iter(L)] ][0]
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```