# How to calculate sum using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

How do I get the cumulative sum of this list using list comprehension:

```
list_comp=[1,4,9,16]
```

Here's what I tried but it prints the double of each item in the list

```
print([x+x for x in list_comp])
```

I expect the results to be:
list_comp=[1,5,14,30] 

But I'm getting this:

```
>> [2, 8, 18, 32]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

List comprehensions are for mapping or filtering of lists. They cannot have an internal state, which is what you would need to do this efficiently.

However in Python 3 there is [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) for that:

```
import itertools

print(list(itertools.accumulate([1, 4, 9, 16])))  # [1,5,14,30]
```

Comment: I think `accumulate` is introduced in Python 3?

Comment: Yes, I will add that. But the question targets Python 3 anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, by combining slicing and a list comprehension, but it is ungainly to do a cumulative sum efficiently.

```
comp=[1,4,9,16] 
[sum(comp[:idx+1]) for idx in range(len(comp))]
```

**I would not recommend using this, it recalculates the sum n times**!

---

A proper way to cumsum can be done like this:

```
def cumsum(seq):
    cumulative = [seq[0]]
    for elt in seq[1:]:
        cumulative.append(cumulative[-1] + elt)
    return cumulative
```

---

`itertools.accumulate` is another way that @NielsWerner demonstrated.

---

Further efficiency can be found with the `numpy` library, and the `cumsum` function of this library.

Answer (score 1):

the walrus operator can help to solve this task:

```
lst = [1,4,9,16] # expected result: [1,5,14,30] 
buf = 0
res = [buf := buf + num for num in lst]
print(res)
```

[Note : walrus operator is introduced in python 3.8]

Comment: walrus operator is introduced in python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,4,9,16] 

b = np.cumsum(a)
print(list(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add one more way of achieving this if you are using Python 2:

```
def cumulative_sum(seq):
    prev = 0
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        result.append(prev+item)
        prev += item
    return result
```

for Python 3 i recommend using built in method `itertools.accumulate`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
list_comp=[1,4,9,16]
b=[sum(list_comp[0:x+1]) for x in range(0,len(list_comp))]
print(b)
```