# is there a way to sum every nth list like a fibonacci sequance in python and became a new list?

Tags: python, list, fibonacci

say we have a `l` list, it made up of 5 or more element which i want to calculate every nth sum in the list just like a fibonacci sequence

`l=[1,5,6,7,2]`

finally i would like to have a new list `l2` which show the sum of every nth element in the `l` list

```
1+5=6
5+6=11
6+7=13
7+2=9
l2=[0,6,11,13,9]
```

i have tried `list2= [sum(l[i:i+i[2]])for i in range(0,len(l),2)]` but it says `int not scriptable`
and i try many more just to stuck please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a `list` comprehension from the `zip` like,

```
>>> l
[1, 5, 6, 7, 2]
>>> [0] + [x+y for x,y in zip(l, l[1:])]
[0, 6, 11, 13, 9]
```

or instead of list comprehension, a generation expression like,

```
>>> [0, *(x+y for x,y in zip(l, l[1:]))]
[0, 6, 11, 13, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `itertools.tee` and `pairwise`:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

[0, *map(sum, pairwise(l))]
```

Output:

```
[0, 6, 11, 13, 9]
```

Comment: hello chris thank for the answer, but i cant call the function because i made the script without one, so if i add the def pairwise the function dont come up when i run the program