# realize cumulative sum with only one line of python code

Tags: python

I came across this problem when in an interview.
The requirement is to realize cumulative sum in one line of python. My answer is

```
def cum_sum(nums):
    return [sum(nums[0:i+1]) for i in range(len(nums))]
```

This is very ugly, the previous result has not been used later which results in redundant calculations. I think there must have some high-level way to implement it.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 4):

See `accumulate` in Python3.2+. That should work.

For your piece of code, the corresponding code would be:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

return list(accumulate(nums))
```

Edit : The updated code is to return a list rather than an iterator.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following ways to get a cumulative sum in one line -

```
nums = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

#Using base python 
[sum(nums[0:i[0]+1]) for i in enumerate(nums)]
#OUTPUT - [10, 30, 60, 100, 150, 210, 280, 360, 450, 550]

#Using Numpy
np.cumsum(nums)
#OUTPUT - array([ 10,  30,  60, 100, 150, 210, 280, 360, 450, 550])
```

Comment: But the complexity has not been reduced. What I want to know is that: To calculate sum(nums[0:n+1]), we could use sum([nums[1:n-1]) + nums[n]. In this way, the number of add operation can be lowered. But I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

Using default value and recursion

**Code**

```
def cum_sum(lst, accum=0):
  return [lst[0] + accum] + accumulate(lst[1:], accum + lst[0]) if lst else []
```

**Test**

```
print(cum_sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])) # Output: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```