# How to iterate through a list using XOR in python

Tags: python, loops, unicode, xor, bin

So I got the following code:

```
telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000*49"
checksum = telegram[10:18]                           # is 00000000
for x in telegram[1:]:
    x = "{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(x)),16))
    print (x)
```

which puts out the binary value of each charakter of the string `telegram`:

```
00110000
00110000
00111011
00110000
00110010
00111011
01000001
00110001
00111011
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00110000
00101010
00110100
00111001
```

Now I want to get the checksum of the telegram, meaning I have to use the bitwise operator `^`. I do get the correct results like this:

```
#--snip--

firstdigit = "{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(telegram[1])),16))            # telegram[1] = 0
result_1 = int(firstdigit) ^ int(checksum)
print (f'{result_1:08}')                                          # is 00110000

seconddigit = "{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(telegram[2])),16))           # telegram[2] =0
result_2 = int(result_1) ^ int(seconddigit)
print (f'{result_2:08}')                                          # is 00000000                    

thirddigit = "{0:08b}".format(int(hex(ord(telegram[3])),16))            # telegram[3] =;
result_3 = int(result_2) ^ int(thirddigit)
print (f'{result_3:08}')                                          # is 00111011
```

...and so on.
(Correct) Output:

```
00110000
00000000
00111011
```

But doing that seems really inconvenient, which brings me to my **actual problem**: I want to loop through the string `telegram` in order to get the desired outputs and I just can't get a hang of it. Would really appreciate it if you could help me out!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It seems that you're asking for a tutorial on loops, XOR, or `map`; this is out of scope.  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  "I can't get the hang of it" is too broad for this site.

Comment: What stops you from using the same type of `for` loop that you already have for initial printout?

Comment: This is probably a job for `itertools.accumulate`. You want to XOR together all the digits of `telegram[1:9]`?

Comment: Er, not `accumulate`: `functools.reduce`, rather.

Comment: Rather all digits of ```telegram``` except the first one (```$```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the conversion to a binary string using the function `ord()` on each character.  For example:

```
>>> telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000*49"
>>> ord(telegram[1]) ^ ord(telegram[2])
0
```

You can convert all the characters to ordinals with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [ord(n) for n in telegram[1:]] # all but first character...
[48, 48, 59, 48, 50, 59, 65, 49, 59, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 42, 52, 57]
```

With tools in the standard library like [functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [operator.xor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) you can XOR all the values together:

```
>>> import functools
>>> import operator
>>> functools.reduce(operator.xor,[ord(n) for n in telegram[1:]])
110
>>> format(110,'08b') # binary if needed
'01101110'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem - and made my code look much easier! Appreciate it!