# Find sum of elements

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sum, iteration

Suppose I have this list. list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6] and I want to find sum of elements of list1 but each time I want too see the sum. Namely to make new list like this sum1 =[1,3,6,10,15,21]. How can I do it with for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
sum_list = []
sum = 0
for element in list:
    sum = sum + element
    sum_list.append(sum)
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use indexing along with `sum`

```
l2 = [sum(list1[:i+1]) for i in range(len(list1))]

print(l2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```