# new value is the sum of old values

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 list A and B, list A contain values I want list B to be the sum of value from list a

```
A = [3,5,7,8,9,12,13,20]
#Wanted result
#B = [3, 8, 15, 23,...77]
#so the new value will be the sum of the old value
# [x1, x2+x1, x3+x2+x1,... xn+xn+xn]
```

what methods I could use to get the answer, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way IMO would be to use `numpy.cumsum`, to get the cumulative sum of your list:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.cumsum(A)
array([ 3,  8, 15, 23, 32, 44, 57, 77])
```

But you also could do it in a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> [sum(A[0:x]) for x in range(1, len(A)+1)]
[3, 8, 15, 23, 32, 44, 57, 77]
```

Another fun way is to use `itertools.accumulate`, which gives accumulated sums by default:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(accumulate(A))
[3, 8, 15, 23, 32, 44, 57, 77]
```

Comment: `itertools.accumulate` or `functools.reduce` is the way to go. For someone who doesn’t know how to add consecutive numbers in a list, `numpy` is overkill.