# Add two numbers next to each other in a list and return output also in list

Tags: python

I want to add two numbers to the list next to each other and return the final answer in a list using python.
for example
my_list = [1,2,3,5,6]
And the final list will be [1,3,5,8,11] for the first digit I will consider the initial value as 0.

I tried this way to get the answer

```
list1 = [1,2,3,0,5,6]

first_value = 0
    new_list = []
    for i,each_value in enumerate(list1):
        if i == 0:
            sum = first_value + each_value
           
        else:
            sum = each_value + prev_val
        new_list.append(sum)
        #i = i+1
        prev_val = each_value
    print(new_list)
```

I have got the output that I want but I wanted to know can we write the same code with less number of lines either by using lambda or some python collection.

Comment: Are you looking for `pairwise`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```py
l = [1,2,3,5,6]

def sum_(l):
    return list(map(lambda e:l[e]+l[e-1] if e!=0 else l[e], range(len(l))))
    

print(sum_(l))
```

OUTPUT `[1, 3, 5, 8, 11]`

##### Explanation

###### I suggest After reading this you need to take a look at the [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

1. I give the map function two parameters one of them is `range(len(l))` If you try to print In the above case this will output to `range(0,5)` Try to transform this into the list `list(range(len(l)))` this will output `[0,1,2,3,4]`.
2. Map function is iterated through this list and set the value of e(provide this is a parameter in lambda function. You can change it to any other name.)
3. In line `map(lambda e:l[e]+l[e-1] if e!=0 else l[e]`. Here I am matching if e is not equal to 0, Because if e is 0 then e-1 is -1 which will point to the last element of the list Which will cause the code to output the wrong output.
4. In my code if e equals 0 then this will return lst[e] else this will return the lst[e]+lst[e-1].

I hope this will explain this .

Comment: Could you please tell me how the 0 will be assigned to e? I am new to this map and lambda function

Comment: @vaanumalar I hope you understand this, I am editing my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) + [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)/[`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,5,6]

out = list(map(sum, zip([0]+my_list, my_list)))
```

output: `[1, 3, 5, 8, 11]`

Or with [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (python ≥ 3.10):

```
from itertools import pairwise

out = my_list[:1]+list(map(sum, pairwise(my_list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In python3.10+, I like to do this:

```
>>> from itertools import pairwise, starmap
>>> from operator import add
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
>>> out = lst[:1]
>>> out.extend(starmap(add, pairwise(lst)))
>>> out
[1, 3, 5, 8, 11]
```

Some test:

```
from itertools import pairwise, starmap
from operator import add
from timeit import timeit


def starmap_add_extend(lst: list):
    out = lst[:1]
    out.extend(starmap(add, pairwise(lst)))
    return out


def map_sum_extend(lst: list):
    out = lst[:1]
    out.extend(map(sum, pairwise(lst)))
    return out


def starmap_add_concat(lst: list):
    return lst[:1] + list(starmap(add, pairwise(lst)))


def map_sum_concat(lst: list):
    return lst[:1] + list(map(sum, pairwise(lst)))


def comperhension_concat(lst: list):
    return lst[:1] + [i + j for i, j in pairwise(lst)]


def generator_extend(lst: list):
    out = lst[:1]
    out.extend(i + j for i, j in pairwise(lst))
    return out


def comperhension(lst: list):
    return [val + lst[i - 1] if i else val for i, val in enumerate(lst)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_lst = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
    for func in (
            starmap_add_extend,
            map_sum_extend,
            starmap_add_concat,
            map_sum_concat,
            comperhension_concat,
            generator_extend,
            comperhension
    ):
        print(func.__name__.ljust(20), timeit(lambda: func(my_lst)))
```

Output:

```
starmap_add_extend   0.5148536000051536
map_sum_extend       0.6762464999919757
starmap_add_concat   0.530809899995802
map_sum_concat       0.7072772000101395
comperhension_concat 0.545955400011735
generator_extend     0.7146139999968
comperhension        0.6786505000200123
```

Comment: @AlbertWinestein Um, How I use? Are you confused about my code or don't you know how to use timeit?

Comment: @AlbertWinestein The first parameter of timeit can accept a nonparametric function or a short code string. The number of iterations is 1 million by default. You can set it through the number parameter.

Comment: Forgive me. I saw your variety of functions but failed to scroll down to see the timeit calls. The window only showed as far as comperhension