# Python `+=` operator in one single line for list

Tags: python, addition, variable-assignment

Now I have a list `a = [1,2,3]`. How could I get result `[1,3,6]` only using one line code?

I can achive it like this , but I want use one line code.

```py
k=0 
arr = [] 
a = [1,2,3] 
for i in a: 
    k+=i 
    arr.append(k) 
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3] 
arr = [sum(a[:i + 1]) for i in range(len(a))] 
print(arr)
```

Comment: It's N square complxcity . I want only count like += opreater

Comment: [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57724791/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it in one line and efficiently, you can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: list(itertools.accumulate(a))
Out[3]: [1, 3, 6]
```

Comment: [How to find the cumulative sum of numbers in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15889203/6045800)