# Create a list from another list in Python, where [i] in list2 = is a counter of list1

Tags: python, list, sum, list-comprehension

From list1

```
list1 = [1654, 2175, 2478, 2132, 2250, 2304, 2258, 2111, 1683, 2036, 2089, 1743, 1920, 1854, 2251, 1505, 1698, 1126, 1695, 1590]
```

I would like to create a second list (list2) which would output the following

```
list2 = [1654, 3829, 6307, 8439, 10689, 12993, 15251, 17362, 19045, 21081, 23170, 24900, 26820, 28674, 30925, 32430, 34128, 35254, 36949, 38539]
```

Realize this will entail a loop of some kind, but I can't get the syntax down.

I have yet to find a good starting point.

Comment: What's the relationship between the two lists?

Comment: List2 is what I want the output to be. It is the sum of all the values from list1. The point is that I do not want to type this out and do the calculations manually, I want to automate the process.

Comment: You are looking for the cumulative sum of values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889131/how-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-numbers-in-a-list

Answer (score 3):

`list2` appears to be a running sum of `list1`. Use a variable that you add to for each element in `list1`, and append that to `list2` each time through the loop.

```
running_sum = 0
list1 = [1654, 2175, 2478, 2132, 2250, 2304, 2258, 2111, 1683, 2036, 2089, 1743, 1920, 1854, 2251, 1505, 1698, 1126, 1695, 1590]
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    running_sum += i
    list2.append(running_sum)
print(list2)
```